# Request a second Access token with different claims post login

Tags: openid-connect

What is the correct method of requesting a second access token (WITH DIFFERENT SCOPES) when the user has logged in with Auth PKCE flow.

Presuming the auth_code returned in the initial flow has expired.

From my understanding

We could recall the authorisation PKCE flow with different scopes which would then give the RP back a code that could be exchanged for the appropriate access token

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution but I think it could be a neater solution

Ive also used IdentityServer 5 to demonstrate it working.

Using a simple MVC app

In Layout.cshtml

//The call to authorize doesn't include a secret so this is safe although pretty ugly

```
<li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href='https://localhost:5001/connect/authorize?client_id=mvc&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5002%2FHome%2FCallback&scope=openid%20api1'>ReAuthFlow</a>
                        </li>
```

The unencoded redirect uri is added to the Client in Config.cs

```
new Client
        {
            ClientId = "mvc",
             ////
            RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc","https://localhost:5002/Home/Callback" },
            // For simplicity I have not required PKCE 
            RequirePkce = false
         }
```

In Home Controller , the Callback method

The Callback method is where we should use the RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync but this needs better documentation (which I'm happy to do if someone can confirm this approach)

```
public async Task CallbackAsync(string code, string state)
{
var client = new HttpClient();
var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:5001");
var request = new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
{
Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
ClientId = "mvc",
ClientSecret = "secret",
RedirectUri = "https://localhost:5002/Home/Callback", // This must be the same as the original callback
Code = code,
GrantType = OidcConstants.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
};
var response = await client.RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(request);

    return await CallApi(response.AccessToken);        
}
```

The new access token now has different scopes